Copy data from x range to a table in the same sheet
I´m new to google script and despite trying different codes I cannot get this to work properly.
I need a script that will copy data from range "SkráStarfsmann" to the next empty row in a table below (with the same number of columns) "NStarfsmenn" in the same sheet when a person clicks the button I drew.
The current code I have been trying to get to work for me is from this question How to copy a range of selected data to after the lastRow of data in the same Sheet using Google Apps Script?

function CopyData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var listToCopy = sheet.getRange("SkráStarfsmann");
  var destRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  listToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange("NStarfsmenn1"));
  listToCopy.clearContent();
}


This is how the columns look in both ranges, the first column "DEILD" is in column B not A.




















DEILD
STARF
KENITALA
NAFN
TEGUND RÁÐNINGAR
BYRJAR
Mánuður
SAKASKRÁ - STAÐA
RÁÐNINGARSAMNINGUR - STAÐA
SAKASKRÁ - STAÐA
ÖNNUR
FASTIR
VEF



I tried to modify various codes from similar questions on this website but none of them worked properly, the current code I have makes it so when the button is clicked the data from range "SkráStarfsmann" is copied to the ENTIRE table, as in all of the rows which is not what I want at all. I think the problem lies in the get.Lastrow line but not sure how to fix it.
I've also gotten an error when I tried to just use the name of the table so instead, I made the rows a range and named it "Nstarfsmenn1".
The other code I tried that semi worked pasted the values starting from column a> but my table starts in column b>.

try:
function CopyData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Define the range to copy from "SkráStarfsmann"
  var listToCopy = sheet.getRange("SkráStarfsmann");

  // Get the number of rows and columns in the range to copy
  var numRows = listToCopy.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = listToCopy.getNumColumns();

  // Define the range "NStarfsmenn"
  var nStarfsmennRange = sheet.getRange("NStarfsmenn");
  
  // Get the values from the range "NStarfsmenn"
  var nStarfsmennValues = nStarfsmennRange.getValues();

  // Calculate the starting row for the next empty row in "NStarfsmenn"
  var nextEmptyRow = nStarfsmennRange.getRow() + nStarfsmennValues.filter(row => row.some(cell => cell)).length;

  // Ensure the target range fits within the sheet dimensions
  if (nextEmptyRow + numRows - 1 > sheet.getMaxRows()) {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getMaxRows(), (nextEmptyRow + numRows - 1) - sheet.getMaxRows());
  }
  
  // Copy the data from "SkráStarfsmann" to the next empty row in "NStarfsmenn"
  listToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(nextEmptyRow, nStarfsmennRange.getColumn(), numRows, numColumns));

  // Clear the content of "SkráStarfsmann"
  listToCopy.clearContent();
}


Thanks for the quick reply! I get this error though "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

@Morrigan updated. try now
